# ajax mvc html: jquery val not preventing call to api

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

When clicking a button I am calling a web api with ajax. My form is using JqueryVal, to make form validations, according to my viewmodel data annotations.

My problem is that when I click the button "Listo" in my form, it calls my API, inspite of jqueryval is marking an error( selecting a file is required)

[image: file selector validation is working]

[image: api is being called]

This is my code:

My viewmodel that contains data annotations(the dataannotations are used along with the `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js`. As you can see, it is working, but is not preventing the API from being called):

```
public class CursoViewModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(125)]
    public string Titulo { get; set; }
    [Required]      
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="selecciona una imagen para tu curso")]
    [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
    public HttpPostedFileBase Imagen { get; set; }
}
```

The class posted to my api

```
public class person
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string surname { get; set; }
}
```

The Api code

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("api/ProfesorCurso/test")]
public string Put(person p)
{
    return p.name + p.surname;
}
```

My View

```
@model project.ViewModels.CourseViewModel
<form id="Editcurso" method="post" action="#">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Please fix the following errors.")
    <div class="container">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(c=>c.Titulo)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.Titulo, new {id="titulo", @class="form-control"})           
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Titulo)
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(c => c.Descripcion)
            @Html.TextAreaFor(c => c.Descripcion, new {id="descripcion", @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Descripcion)
        </div>
        <div class="thumbnail" id="imagencurso"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Imagen)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Imagen, new {id="imagen" ,type = "file", data_rule_validCustomer = "true" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Imagen)
        </div>
        <button id="submiter" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Listo!</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

The scripts in the view

```
@section scripts
{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#submiter").click(function () {
                jQuery.support.cors = true;
                var person = new Object();
                person.name = "Sourav";
                person.surname = "Kayal";
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/api/ProfesorCurso/test',
                    type: 'PUT',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: person,
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        return false;
                    },
                    error: function (x, y, z) {
                        alert('error al postear');
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

What can I do to prevent ajax to call my api when clicking my form button, if there are Jquery validation errors?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be handling the `.submit()` event of the form, and then your can check `.valid()`, and if not cancel the ajax call. Note you should also be cancelling the default submit.

```
$('#Editcurso').submit(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default submit
    if (!$(this).valid()) {
        return; // exit the function and display the errors
    }
    ....
    $.ajax({
        ....
    });
}
```

As a side note, there is no point adding `new { id="titulo" }` etc - the `HtmlHelper` methods that generate form controls already add an `id` attribute based on the property name

Comment: wow! this is so nice! after two days trying and trying I got it working!!!
thanks

Comment: Pleasure, but I'm still a bit confused about what your actually doing here - your view is based on `CourseViewModel` but you posting back data for `person` - where do you submit the data for `CourseViewModel`?

Comment: I used person as an example to simplify my debuging. I did it because I could not call my api properly with AJAX.
Actually I am not posting back anything in a "normal" way (meaning that I post back to an mvc controller), I am using just ajax to update or post things to my backend.